# How would I set up audio streaming from a Node server to React frontend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, audio-streaming

I'm trying to create a radio broadcast app as a small project for learning. A potential implementation involves storing writeable streams (in this case, responses) in a list, and writing mp3 data from a readable stream like so

```
readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
for (const writable of writables) {
    writable.write(chunk);
}
});
```

The front end would look something like this:

```
class Player extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <audio key = {this.props.title}  controls autoPlay muted
                    src='/stream' type="audio/mp3"/>
                <div>Current Playing: {this.props.title}</div>
                <button onClick={this.props.playNext}>Next</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

For the time being, I'm using throttle with a constant value to slow the stream transfer rate. However, I can't get any sound to play. I've tried using pipe inside of the /stream call

```
        // readable.pipe(res);
```

and it does play the sound, but isn't valid for my purposes, since a radio should have all listeners on approximately the same chunks at the same time. I'm not getting any error messasges, so I'm struggling to figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

ReactJS

```
<ReactAudioPlayer
  src={`http://localhost:3001/api/report/${asteriskid}`}
  autoPlay
  controls
/>
```

NodeJS

```
exports.getAudio = async(req, res) => {
try {
    const AUDIO_PATH= process.env.RECORDING_PATH;
    const cdrRepository = getRepository(Cdr);
    const { uniqueid } = req.params;
    const call = await cdrRepository.find({
        select: ['recording'],
        where: {
            uniqueid : uniqueid
        }
    });
    const audio = path.join(__dirname, AUDIO_PATH, String(call[0].recording));
    const stat = fs.statSync(audio);
    
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/wav',
        'Content-Length': stat.size
    });

    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(audio);
    readStream.pipe(res);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(`Error: ${e}`)
}}
```